# Issue echoing links PHP MySQL, missing code

Tags: php

I am having trouble with my code. I want to display posts on one page grouped by category but I also need the titles of the posts to be links to the actual articles, everything I’ve tried so far has broken. Can anyone help? I can echo the titles just not as links!

Comment: So construct  your href links in the same loop

Comment: Since you are concatenating the titles in your query, it won't be easy to split them later!

Answer (score 1):

You should take the excellent advice from @Marten and @CharlesAddis in the comments, and if you don't want to use an ORM, you should at least use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

However, to give an answer for answer's sake:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<h2>".$row['category']."</h2>"."<br />";
        $titles = explode(", ",$row['titles']);
        foreach ($title as $t) {
            echo '<a href="' . $t . '">' . $t . '</a><br>';
        }
        echo "<hr />";
    }
```

I'm not sure what the relation between post titles and post links are, if you can add that I can update the answer.